# How to get element id in client-side javascript in Orbeon Forms?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, orbeon, xforms

I'm new to XHTML, XForm, and Orbeon, and I've got a question in regards to retrieving HTML element ID using client-side javascript in Orbeon Forms. In normal HTML I'd just used the getElementById function, and Orbeon's documentation suggest a [function](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/client-side-javascript-api.html#getting-and-setting-controls-value) for retrieving the value of an element (controller in their terminology).

> ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(controlIdOrElement)

However, with an Orbeon From (snippet) such as

```
<xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
  <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
     <xf:bind id="cvr-input-bind" name="cvr-input" ref="cvr-input"/>

  (...)

<fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
  <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
    <fr:grid>
      <xh:tr>
        <xh:td>
          <xf:input id="cvr-input-control" bind="cvr-input-bind">
            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/cvr-input/label"/>
            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/cvr-input/hint"/>
            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
          </xf:input>
        </xh:td>
  (...)
```

the getValue function doesn't find a value on any of the parameter variants

- cvr-input
- cvr-input-control
- cvr-input-bind

given as a string.

When I inspect the generated form I see that the input element has gotten the id *section-1-control≡xf-383≡cvr-input-control*, to which it makes sense that getValue cannot find it on the three variants above.

I've made a trigger button--shown below--that produces the intended result (map the input value to another controller/element), but I can't imagine the solution would have to involve hard-coding the section-parts of the element ID.

Thus my question is: **how do I retrieve an element/controller (or its value) when the coded ID is modified in the final view?**

```
<xf:trigger id="get-pnumbers-btn-control" bind="get-pnumbers-btn-bind">
  <xf:label ref="$form-resources/get-pnumbers-btn/label"/>
  <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/get-pnumbers-btn/hint"/>
  <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
  <xxf:script ev:event="DOMActivate" type="javascript">
    var cvrInputElementId = "section-1-control≡xf-383≡cvr-input-control";
    var cvrOutputElementId = "section-1-control≡xf-383≡cvr-output-control";
    var cvrInput = ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(cvrInputElementId);
    ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(cvrOutputElementId, cvrInput);
  </xxf:script>
</xf:trigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`xxf:client-id()` function](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-controls.html#xxfclientid) resolves an id and returns the client id. That could be helpful. Then you need somehow to pass that id to the script (which is [easy](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/actions/scripting.html#passing-parameters) with the upcoming 4.11 but a bit harder previously).

You can also use jQuery, finding an element with `id` ending with a certain string:

```
var clientId = ORBEON.jQuery('[id $= "cvr-input-control"]').attr('id')
```

There is an RFE to [improve the id scheme](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1136).

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Ended up using the jQuery solution since I'm most likely not going to be working in 4.11; just not very well versed in the library so hadn't thought of that solution.